# OpenMp C Fileoutput

Tags: c, openmp

I remembered to have some trouble with OpenMp and writing into files in parallel, therefore I wrote a simple testprogram that creates files for every for iteration and counts down to zero in the file. Surprisingly it seems to work! 
If I open the taskmanager with top, I see always just one cpu with a load around 90% and the others around 1%-5%. Is it because the task is not cpu heavy or is there something going wrong (sometimes 2-3 cpus go up to 40%)?

The Testprogram

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<omp.h>

void print2file(char filename[],int i){
  FILE *fp;
  int j;
  fp=fopen(strcat(filename,".txt"),"w");
  for(j=i;j>=0;j--)
    fprintf(fp,"%d\n",j);
  fclose(fp);
}

int main(){
  int i;
  char test[12];
  #pragma omp for
  for(i=0;i<1000000000;i++){
    sprintf(test,"%d",i);
    //printf("test %d",i);
    print2file(test,i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#pragma omp for` need to be in a parallel region. Either use `#pragma omp parallel` followed by `#pragma omp for` inside, or a shortcut `#pragma omp parallel for`.

---

Note that you need `i` and `test` to be thread-local variables, not shared ones, to prevent data race. There are many ways how to achieve this, such as declaring these variables inside a parallel region, make them `private`/`firstprivate` in an OpenMP clause, make them `threadprivate`, etc.

Comment: I removed my answer, because this probably goes more to the core of the problem. However I still recommend that OP (or anyone coming across this code) reconsiders the idea creating a billion files in a single directory.

Comment: @visibleman In my experience, there is typically no speedup for I/O operations. Unless you have some parallel file system, but even then, speedups are typically achieved only with distributed parallelism (accessing a file system from multiple nodes of some cluster/supercomputer). It depends on the number or I/O controllers per node.

Comment: No My point is that ops current code creates a billion output files. Which seems kind of silly for an omp test.

Comment: The most pressing issue after adding `parallel` is the race condition on `test`.

Comment: @Zulan It depends on where you add it. If `#pragma omp parallel` is above the declarations of `i` and `test`, then it will be ok.

Comment: Of course, I think it is critical to include that explanation in the answer.

Comment: Oh, it worked, thx! And yeah, I need private for test, I was wondering why that would work without the private statement. It wasn't running parallel before...